# How can I get hibernate to show up on my power menu?

Tags: windows-8, hibernate

I've done my Google searches and it just doesn't want to show up.

[image]

This setting does not exist on my laptop after following the directions.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power` has `HibernateEnabled` set to `1`, and I can confirm that I have a `hiberfil.sys` of over 6 gb.  If I open up `cmd` and run `shutdown -h`, it hibernates successfully and wakes up successfully after pressing the power button to boot back up.  The results of `powercfg -a` are:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (Connected)
    Hibernate
    Fast Startup
```

`Standby (S1)` and `Standby (S2)` are not supported by my system firmware and `Standby (S3) (Hybrid Sleep)` is unavailable when connected standby is supported. Is there something else I can do to get it to show up?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of poking around, I finally found an option in Local Policy Editor to add it in.  Open up `gpedit.msc` and navigate to `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `Windows Components` > `File Explorer`. Enable `Show hibernate in the power options menu`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful to you, but if you can't figure it out, you can make a notepad fil on your desktop that says "shutdown -h" (without the quotes) and save it as *.bat and double clicking that will put your machine into hibernation.